# Change material emission for a second then go back to default

Tags: c#, unity

I'm looking for a way to change the emission of a material for a second then get it back to where is was by default

Here's what I have for now

```
float emission_lvl = 5.0F;
float emission_lvl_start = 0.5F;

public Update(){
    mat.SetFloat("_Emission",emission_lvl);
    Invoke ("SetEmissionBack", 1.0f);
}

public void SetEmissionBack(){
    mat.SetFloat("_Emission",emission_lvl_start);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your placement is wrong. Execute same code of `Update` in `Start` or whenever you want to execute it and remove it from `Update`. Because `Update` is a loop that executes 30 - 60 (depends) per second and `mat.SetFloat("_Emission",emission_lvl);` executing per frame, that is preventing to change material's emission property.

And now I came to know that you want flicker effect. So you can use `Coroutine` for that.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("StartEffect");
}

IEnumerator StartEffect()
{
    while(true) // Or any other condition, this will repeat until this condition is true
    {
        mat.SetFloat("_Emission",emission_lvl);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        mat.SetFloat("_Emission",emission_lvl_start);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: On `Start()` it will only run it 1 time... I need a flicker effect

Comment: SO you want to executes like on and off?  1 second on and 1 second off? or anything else?

Comment: Yes and repeats

Comment: Check the edits

Comment: Seems that the delay not working. Both are taken in consideration at the same time each seconds. I need a delay between each `setFloat()`

Comment: Double check the code and match it.. And remove your code from update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35658/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-warface).

Comment: Check the edits

Comment: You may want to use [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) for this.  As-written this will create a new material instance once every second, requiring the old (now unused) copies to get garbage collected.

Comment: @Draco18s you are right here too. But again, my theory :)

Comment: @HamzaHasan :-)